# Openlayers draw feature : save map state

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, openlayers, draw

I am a newbie in Openlayers API. I am using the Draw Features. I grabbed the source code of this page: [Draw Features](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html) 
Now I want to add the *save button* to the webpage so I can continue working on the same edited map.
Please help.
Thank you so much !!

Comment: What do you mean by "so I can continue working on the same edited map"?

Comment: For example, if i had drawn something in the map, when i open the page next time, I want to find the drawn objects and continue to draw and use the map.

Comment: Ok.. so, did you want to save it do a database somewhere, or in the browser cookies or what? This question far too vague to answer.

Comment: Exactly, i want to save the progress in a database

Comment: Ok, so which part of that do you need help with. What have you tried. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector formats with GeoJSON.
Did you try this?
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html